# I upgraded from 16.04 to 20.04 when prompted online. My signal dropped out and now I have a blank screen. Help

Tags: boot, upgrade, 20.04

I then downloaded 20.04 and booted from usb and reinstalled the upgrade. That didn't work any better. When I start the machine it seems to be booting (purple screen and then 'Ubuntu' & timing dots and then nothing, just a blank screen.
My computer is a Dell Inspiron 5720.

Comment: I'm confused that your title says "upgraded", but your description seems to indicate a clean-install. Please ensure that your question is clear so that the answers are helpful.

Comment: When the boot screen is less then helpful, you might want to try switching to a different virtual terminal (VT) using Alt-F1..12. Maybe you can get helpful output on any of these other VTs.

Comment: My first attempt was an offered 'upgrade' whilst online, but my wifi dipped out for a short time in the middle of the process. I then did a download on another machine to make a bootable usb memory stick, I booted from this and the option said that I could upgrade from 20.04 to 20.04 (!) or completely replace 20.04 which would result in wiping all my files! Of course, having upgraded many times in the past with no problem, I hadn't backed up said files....... :-(   Doh!